# How to use rust quick_xml to read an xml file and print the events as they are read in?

Tags: xml, rust

This seems like it should be a standard kind of example but I am not finding it. In the match look you can handle events. But you get all kinds of weird objects with no idea how to just get the data out.

Want something like `(event-type: start,stop etc, tag, attrib, text)` for each event. Can do whatever you want if you have that generator.

```
    loop {

        match reader.read_event_into(&mut buf) {
            Err(e) => panic!("Error at position {}: {:?}", reader.buffer_position(), e),
            Ok(Event::Eof) => break,
            Ok(Event::Start(e)) => {
                let attrib = e.attributes().map(|a| a.unwrap().value).collect::<Vec<_>>();
                println!("start: prefix={:?}, local_name={:?}, attrib={:?}", e.name().prefix(), e.name().local_name(), attrib);
            }
            Ok(Event::Text(e)) => {
                txt.push(e.unescape().unwrap().into_owned());
                println!("text: e={:?}", e);
                println!("start: txt={:?}, e={:?}", txt, e);
            }
            Ok(Event::End(e)) => {
                println!("end: name={:?}, e={:?}", e.name(), e);
            }
            _ => (),
        }
...
```

And if it's easier, want to eventually just pump this to PyObjects and a generator via PyO3.  But this is mostly about quick_xml usage.